# Same MOSFET component but reversed arrow

Tags: mosfet, schematics, powermosfet, reverse-polarity

I'm trying to implement a USB PD controller, STUSB4500, but the typical application example shows 2x P-Channel MOSFETs STL6P3LLH6 with different arrow indications. I'm now confused about the pins, T4 has the same MOSFET drawing as in the STL6P3LLH6 datasheet, so the left pin is the drain (5,6,7,8) and the right source (1,2,3). But for T1, which is reversed, is the right side pins 5,6,7,8 or 1,2,3? Any further clarifications on this will be appreciated.

Image Sources/Datasheet links:

STUSB4500: https://www.st.com/en/interfaces-and-transceivers/stusb4500.html

STL6P3LLH6: https://www.st.com/en/power-transistors/stl6p3llh6.html

[image: STL6P3LLH6]

[image: STUSB4500]

Comment: Google "back to back MOSFETs".

Comment: Emerson - Hi, (a) To comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] your question & add the PDF / video / webpage name & *link* to the source of each copied / adapted image. (b) Did you mean the **S**TUSB4500? Doing a quick search, I couldn't find a USB PD controller with the TUSB4500 part number. TY

Comment: thank you @SamGibson, this has been fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two sources (1,2,3) are connected together. The grey thick line has obscured the internal connection from body to source.

This is a standard back-to-back MOSFET connection to make a bilateral switch.

[image]